# Como alterar a Porta no DataSnap Server pelo arquivo INI

Tags: delphi, datasnap

Estou tentando configurar um arquivo **INI** para ficar de livre acesso ao cliente, para poder conectar no serviço pela porta que o mesmo determinou.

Consigo sem problemas nenhum, alterar em modo design, compilo o projeto executo e começa a funcionar na porta conforme o esperado. No entanto, preciso que o serviço pegue a porta do arquivo INI, ele sempre pega do modo design, já tentei alterar antes de iniciar o serviço mas não tive sucesso.

Eu crio projeto pelo seguinte caminho:

**File->New->Other->DataSnap Server**

Como eu altero o número da porta?

**OBS:** Estou usando o *Delphi XE7*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

Quando você cria o projeto DataSnap Server, uma das classes responsáveis pela conexão e a comunicação é o `ServerContainerUnit`, nessa classe contém um componente de conexão chamado `DSServer1` que por padrão vem como `AutoStart` ativado.

Para resolver o meu problema, desativei o `AutoStart` do componente, e no Create, acrescentei o código:

```
DSHTTPService1.SetHttpPort(porta);
DSServer1.Start;
```